# Do Talents stack together, multiplying bonuses?

Tags: shadow-of-the-demon-lord

Do talents stack together to multiply boons and extra damage?

For example:

1. A rogue attacking with Trickery/Backstab/Dirty tricks (1 boon, +3d6 dam).
2. A rogue using Trickery and Subterfuge at rank 2? (2 boons)

Comment: Hello and welcome! If you have time please take the [tour] to find out more about how the site works. I have made an edit to your question in an attempt to improve it. If you don't like it or feel that I have changed the intent of your question feel free to rollback the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, they stack

But keep in mind that each talent has a different condition to work, except for **Trickery**, which adds a boon on all checks.

**Backstab** and **Trickery** only add extra damage if you have at least a boon on your attack, meaning that if your table runs with the default rule of 1 boon cancelling 1 bane, a single bane (such as darkness, fog, poor weapon quality, etc) is enough to remove this extra damage from your attacks.

So it's common to combine trickery, for the extra boon, with **Backstab**, which cause an extra +1d6 damage if you have a boon on your check *and* you use a swift or basic weapon (so no crossbows or two-handed axes). While a warrior, on the other hand, has a flat +1d6 damage on all damage (and another +1d6 if the attack is 20+), but does not gain a free boon on the attack itself.

Finally, **Dirty Trick** (at 5th) adds an extra damage if you make an attack with at least 1 boon, so it works much simpler than the other two talents, as this boon isn't required to be from *Trickery*. As long you have a boon you deal an extra 1d6.

So, you will eventually have multiple boons and multiple banes on the same check, and all these extra d6s will be applied if the required conditions are met.

### Combining boons and banes

If you check the core book (pg 32), we have the following:

> Boons and banes cancel each other out, one for one. If 2 boons and 1 bane apply to a particular d20 roll, you make the roll with 1 boon (**1 bane cancels 1 boon**). Similarly, if 2 boons and 4 banes apply to the roll, you would end up making the roll with 2 banes (2 boons cancel 2 banes).

This means that, as a rogue, you want to avoid banes, or figure out ways to gain additional boons on your attacks so you can cancel the banes and make your attacks with a boon, such as feinting (adds 2 boons on your next attack), attacking an immobilized creature (add 1 boon), or even attacking a prone target (also add 1 boon).

Comment: Ok, so assuming I have no banes, **Trickery** combine with **Backstab** would give me d20 + 1 boon? On a hit, I would do weapon dam + 2d6 right? (1d6 from Trickery and 1d6 from Backstab)

Comment: That is correct.